# Post a notification in .c file

Tags: ios, c, notifications, progress-bar

A progress bar is used to show us the percentage of email that has been delivered. Im using `libetpan.xcodeproj` to send email and the percentage can be calculated in the following code. It is written in c. Problem is how could I post a notification in c.file to tell the observer (it is an objective-c class) that the percentage has been increased. Any help is appreciated:)

**mailstream_helper.c**

```
static inline int send_data_crlf_progress(mailstream * s,
                      const char *message, size_t size,
                      int quoted, size_t progr_rate,
                      progress_function * progr_fun,
                      mailprogress_function *
                      progr_context_fun, void *context)
{
    const char *current;
    size_t count;
    size_t last;
    size_t remaining;

    count = 0;
    last = 0;

    current = message;
    remaining = size;

    int i = 0;
    while (remaining > 0) {
        ssize_t length;

        if (quoted) {
            if (current[0] == '.')
                if (mailstream_write(s, ".", 1) == -1)
                    goto err;
        }

        length = send_data_line(s, current, remaining);
        if (length < 0)
            goto err;

        current += length;

        count += length;
        if (progr_rate != 0) {
            if (count - last >= progr_rate) {
                if (progr_fun != NULL) {
                    (*progr_fun) (count, size);
                }
                if (progr_context_fun != NULL) {
                    (*progr_context_fun) (count, size, context);
                }
                last = count;
            }
        }

        remaining -= length;
        //I need to post a notification here to let my
            //progress bar know how much data has been sent.        
        printf("No.%d rateOfSentData:%d end\r\n", ++i,
               1.0 - (float) remaining / (float) size);

    }

    return 0;

err:
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the file to have a .m suffix. It's now a ObjC file with pure C code in it (now). Then add a message at end to send a notification as you would elsewhere using NSNotificationCenter.

If for some reason this rename cannot be done have it call a c function that you then add to an existing .m file to do notification.

Comment: Yew, we solve the problem by rename the file with .m suffix. It works fine now:) Many thanks:)